# How can I user session_start() in a loop with no warning/error?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to implement a Server-Sent Event where the server will send the clients new messages.

The challenge here is that the server updated sessions and then echo their content.

The problem is that I will need to have that in one infinite loop.

Here is what I have done.

```
    while(true){


        session_start();
        header("Content-Type: text/event-stream" . PHP_EOL);
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache" . PHP_EOL);

        //configure the connection
        $conf = new ICWS\Config\Config($url, $stationName); 

        //create a new instance of icws
        $attrebutes = array('AccoRDI_mid','AccoRDI_account_id');
        $icws = new ICWS\Connection($conf, $attrebutes, true); 

        $messaging = new ICWS\Messaging($icws);

        $messaging->processMessages();
        session_write_close();

        $result = $messaging->getCallsQueue();

        echo 'event: getMessagingQueue' . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'data: ' . json_encode( $result) . PHP_EOL;    

        ob_end_flush();
        flush(); 

        usleep($sleepTime * 1000000);
    }
```

The problem here is that I get the following warning/notices

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent and 

Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete or flush i
```

The reason that I need the `session_start()` in the loop is because I will need to unlock the session file immediately after reading it before the script sleeps. 
The idea is to

1. Start/resume session
2. Update session values
3. Display the content of the session
4. Unlock/release the session to allow other processes to use it
5. Go back to step 1

What can I do to avoid the errors here?

Comment: can`t you use a cron task at 5 seconds ?

Comment: "How can I user session_start() in a loop with no warning/error?" you can't

Comment: I need to implement server-sent events here is more info about what I am doing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873956/server-sent-events-polling-causing-long-delays

Comment: @Dagon is there alternative solution/work around to this problem?

Comment: I may be wrong, but maybe you can use `session_write_close`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case... I would do *without* sessions. A session is just a serialized object into a temporary (well, garbage-collected) file. Who's to stop you from writing your own alternate session handler?

In its most basic form, leaving aside error checking and recovery, it's something like

```
function getAlternateSessionData() {
    $raw = file_get_contents(getAlternateSessionFileName());
    return unserialize($raw);
}
```

and the same with `file_put_contents()` to save the session. You do have to consider how to guard against concurrent access to the same session file by two different server processes. But you can send the session ID cookie at the beginning only, thus never actually "restarting" the session.

Another possibility would be to implement your alternate session using memory - if the server process does not terminate - or something like Redis (you can do that with ordinary sessions too, but *those* would send a session cache limiter).

You can also use [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) to override the file reading and writing functions of PHP with functions of your own, leaving all the session handling (cookies, etc.) intact. By handling yourself the session file management, you would be able to commit the session whenever you wanted. **Still, you would need to consider carefully how to go with concurrent access to the session files, even if they are compatible with PHP's own session handler** (if they aren't, you will have to include your session handler in every script accessing the "new" sessions).

As for `ob_end_flush()`, I believe that's because you never did call `ob_start()`. You can check the ob* level using `ob_get_level()` and flush it securely before the loop using `ob_end_clean()`, *then* instate a `ob_start()`/`ob_end_flush()` pair inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like the idea of creating my own data saving mechanism. The only questions that come to my mind are, what will be the filename? Where would I store it? How to delete the file after is is not longer used? I mean if a user just close their browser, the server somehow will need to remove the file as garbage.

Comment: You will need garbage collection (as PHP itself does). Or a daemon; you could store session information using Redis, as I said, and let it do whatever it needs to be done. If you go with session_save_handler, garbage collection will be done automatically by PHP.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote a class the handles the cache outside the sessions. thank you for your advise

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting the session for each loop, start it only if it hasn't already been started.

For PHP 5.4 and higher:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
     session_start();
}
```

For PHP 5.3 and lower:

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

You can't call `ob_end_flush()` without calling `ob_start()` first, but You can just use `ob_flush()` for what you are trying to do.

Lastly, are you doing this in a browser?  The browser will give up on the page if it takes to long too respond, and looping indefinitely will eventually cause a time out.  You'd be better off using ajax/javascript, or a meta refresh tag instead of looping on the PHP side.