# How to run EventSource inside Shared Worker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, server-sent-events, shared-worker

I implemented [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) to receive messages from the server. I describe how I implemented it on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143150/is-there-a-way-to-make-using-server-sent-events-persistent)

Now I am trying to run it inside a [shared worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Shared_workers) to prevent the user from opening multiple connections to the servers via multiple browser tabs.

Here is what I have done to run the code inside a Shared Worker

created a file calles `worker.js` and I put this code inside of it

```
self.addEventListener('getMessagingQueue', function (event) {
    console.log('Listener is Available');
    var thisp = this;
    var eventSrc = new EventSource('poll.php');

    eventSrc.addEventListener('getMessagingQueue', function (event) {

    var message = JSON.parse(event.data);

    thisp.postMessage(message);

    }, false);

}, false);
```

Then when the HTML page loads I call this code

```
$(function(){       

        var worker  = new SharedWorker('worker.js');

        worker.addEventListener('getMessagingQueue', function (event) {
          var message = event.data;

          console.group('Message Received');
          console.log( message );
          console.groupEnd();

        }, false);

    });
```

But the code is not returning messages from the server.

How can I correctly run `EventSource` event inside the shared worker?

Comment: What is `getMessagingQueue`? Afaik, workers only emit `message` and `error` events.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your comment. the `getMessagingQueue` is the name of the event returned by poll.php

Comment: Yeah, on the `EventSource`, but you cannot use the same event name on the worker - there's only `onmessage`.

Comment: Got you, okay better, but I get this error in the console `ReferenceError: EventSource is not defined` which is referencing line 5 of the `worker.js`

Comment: Hm, [looks like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers) `EventSource` is not supported in workers :-/

Comment: This post show how they implemented it but I am unable to replicate his code https://gist.github.com/rwaldron/552549

Comment: Maybe the support is browser-specific. You might want to contact Rick on how he made that gist work.

Comment: does it make more since to use WebSocket?

Comment: `WebSockets` seem to be supported in Workers at least, yes.

Comment: …though actually SSE [should work](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2012AprJun/0263.html) as well

Comment: Hum, so why is it not working for me?

Comment: Firefox currently does not support `EventSource` in web/shared workers [Bug 876498](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=876498)

Comment: [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make EventSource available inside SharedWorker in FireFox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321295/how-to-make-eventsource-available-inside-sharedworker-in-firefox)